# Understanding frequency sweep results on superconducting quantum computers

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, superconducting-quantum-computing

I have run some frequency sweep experiments on ibm_osaka quantum computer from IBM. The experiment is presented here in detail: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html#frequencysweep and the results are shown below.

[image]

[image]

The first image shows results in the 4.4–5.2 GHz range. One can see the peak at 4.82 GHz corresponding to the resonance frequency of the first qubit. The second image shows results in the 5.2–7.6 GHz range and one can see a second peak at roughly 7.2 GHz. What is the physical origin of this peak? I don't think this peak corresponds to the 0-2 transition, the frequency is too small. Can these results be explained by an ideal qubit or this indicates some residual coupling with the environment?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the exact experiment you performed to generate these graphs?

Comment: The question was updated with a link towards a description of the experiment.

Comment: I believe the second peak at ~7 GHz is the resonator frequency. Due to driving at high power, the circuit is escaping from the Josephson energy well. Although, I am not entirely sure.